# "Chalice" vs. "goblet"

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

Is there a difference between *chalice* and *goblet*, other than (maybe) religious connotations on the word *chalice*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the final analysis, the words describe objects which are fairly equivalent.

A *[goblet](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/goblet)* is:

> a drinking glass with a foot and stem.

A [*chalice*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chalice) has a broader definition, but this is mainly balanced out by the fact that the third meaning is rare, and the fact that you specified differences *other than* relating to the first definition:

> **1.**
>   Ecclesiastical.
>        a.) a cup for the wine of the Eucharist or Mass.
>        b.) the wine contained in it.
>
> **2.** a drinking cup or goblet
>
> **3.** a cuplike blossom

As to usage differences: the terms are both [in use](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=chalice,goblet&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), though *goblet* seems to be the [more popular](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=goblet#q=goblet&hl=en&prmd=ivns&source=univ&tbm=shop&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=c6FdTr7_Lerk0QHS9tH7Ag&ved=0CGgQrQQ&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=f6e5f660e66620ab&biw=1366&bih=643) word to use in terming gourmet wineglasses and other goblet-shaped glassware, where *chalice* has a [more rich](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=goblet#ds=pr&pq=goblet&hl=en&cp=5&gs_id=j&xhr=t&q=chalice&pf=p&sclient=psy&tbm=shop&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=chali&aq=0&aqi=g5&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=f6e5f660e66620ab&biw=1366&bih=643), historical feel, often describing ornate metal goblets.  You might drink out of a goblet, but look at a chalice in a museum, or put it on your mantelpiece.

Comment: So goblet is a subclass of chalice?  Every goblet is a chalice; but not every chalice is a goblet, since some chalices are drinking cups and some are blossoms.

Comment: Yes, but the other definitions of *chalice* are not as common as the one meaning *goblet*, so they are almost synonyms.  (E.g. when I think "chalice", I envision a goblet.)

Comment: If you look at images.google.com, the main difference I see is that very few "chalices" are made of clear glass, whereas lots of "goblets" are. But both "chalices" and "goblets" typically have a foot and stem.

Answer (score -1):

The meanings are similar.

Goblet has more masculine/course conotation while chalice is more feminine/refined.

Comment: Similar does not mean the same.